# Negative reflection coefficient question

Tags: transmission-line, reflection

If I have a transmission line with a reflection coefficient of -0.3, and I feed it an input voltage of 5V, will my net voltage at the reflection point be

(1 - 0.3)*5 = 3.5V

or

(1 + 0.3)*5 = 6.5V

Came across this problem a couple of days ago and I'm still not quite sure whether or not the reflection coefficient being negative makes a difference to the outcome.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The amplitude at the end is **(1+coefficient)A**:

[From this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171557/what-and-whys-of-termination/171617), the following animation shows the wave on a shorted transmission line. The coefficient is -1, so the amplitude is (1-1)A=0 :

[image]

The other extreme is an open end, were the amplitude is (1+1)A=2A:

[image]

Comment: Okay, so in this case, given that the coefficient is 0.3, obviously the final answer should be 3.5V